# Sort then dedup a rust vector of integer in one line

Tags: rust

I want to sort then dedup a vector of `i32` in rust:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![5,5,3,3,4,4,2,1,2,1];
    
    vec.sort().collect().dedup();
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

This code does not work, but if the `dedup` part is done this way, it's fine:

```
vec.sort();
vec.dedup();
```

How do I do `sort` and `dedup` in one line in my example ?

Comment: Why is doing it in one line important?

Comment: You could always make your own versions of dedup and sort that return &mut Self, so you can chain them. Just not sure of the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html), you can do:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![5,5,3,3,4,4,2,1,2,1];
    
    vec = vec.into_iter().sorted().dedup().collect();
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

It really depeonds on *why* you think you need a one-liner though. If it's *actually* because you need a single expression then you can use a block:

```
vec = {
    vec.sort();
    vec.dedup();
    vec
};
```